# Transit via UK for 43 hours for GC holder

Tags: visas, usa, uk, transit

We are the nationals of Ukraine, currently live in the US and hold Green cards for all family members. We will be travelling to Ukraine via London and we have 42 hours layover between the flights (arrive at 11.15 pm day 1, depart at 5 pm day 3)). I read on uk.gov website that we should be allowed to exist the airport since we have green cards, but I am slightly concerned that we have more than 24 hour connection. Can please someone help sharing your knowledge if this is something we should be able to do? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note specifically the rule that transit without visa is only allowed if you "have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive." It appears your itinerary doesn't quite qualify.

Comment: You would need to go through immigration after midnight to qualify here. You might be able to do it if the flight is on time or late, but your airline would be required to deny boarding. Consider rescheduling your US-London flight segment.